# Transferring files from Windows share to Android

Tags: java, android, network-programming

I need to dynamically acquire a set of .png files in an Android app. 
Is there a way to **transfer files from a Windows share (requiring username/password, even?) to the Android device for further display?** 
I know certain File Explorer apps can do this via GUI, but is the java code for this an "obvious" solution or something that requires a lot of work? (Worrying about time constraints here)

Thanks for any ideas/hints.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: It was actually rather simple by using [jCIFS](https://jcifs.samba.org/), which lets you log onto Windows Shares.

For example:

```
UniAddress domain = UniAddress.getByName(ipAddress);

NtlmPasswordAuthentication authentication = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(ipAddress, Username, Password);
SmbSession.logon(domain, authentication);
String remotepath = "smb://" + ipAddress + "/" + [Insert Folder here];
SmbFile remoteDir = new SmbFile(remotepath, authentication);
```

Then continue using the SmbFile in the usual manner (e.g. for reading from an SmbFile, call smbFile.getInputStream() )